# Set the valuer of selected combobox item in c# windows universal

Tags: c#, combobox

This is my combo box

```
<ComboBox
 Name="truck_trypes_combo"
 DisplayMemberPath="description"
 SelectedValuePath="id"
 Header="Truck category"
>
```

Am setting its itemsource via

```
  TruckTypesSqlite truckypessqlite = new TruckTypesSqlite();
  truck_trypes_combo.ItemsSource = truckypessqlite.GetAllTruckTypes();
```

In my  TruckTypesqlite

```
class TruckTypesSqlite {

      public List<TruckTypesModel> GetAllTruckTypes()

      {
          //fetch data from sqlite and return a list of type TruckTypesModel
      }

  }
```

The `TruckTypesModel` class consists of an id and description properties.

The above works but am now how do i set the selected item of the combobox suppose that i have an id of 25

After a few research i found out that i need to set the `SelectedIndex` being new to c# how do i get the index of a value like 25 in the list returned by GetAllTruckTypes() so that i can simply do

```
public void setSeletedValue(){
   //set the index of id value 25
    truck_trypes_combo.SelectedIndex = ;//index of id value 25

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void setSeletedValue(int id)
{
    var allTruckTypes = truckypessqlite.GetAllTruckTypes();
    int index = allTruckTypes.FindIndex(t => t.id == id);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        truck_trypes_combo.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

You may also need to improve the code by making `allTruckTypes` a public property so it can be reused in multiple methods, also use data binding for the `SelectedItem` of the combo box instead of setting its SelectedIndex explicitly.

But since you have just started to use C#, I am just showing you how to find the item (and its index) from the list.